# How can I test a Kohana Project?

Tags: kohana

i need some help with the Kohana framework.

I have a project developed with Kohana and a would like to test it on my development environment.

I'm reading the Ebook "Kohana 3.0 Develop professional web applications with Kohana Beginner's Guide. But i still have very difficulties with this framework.

It's very difficult to search guides about it, even here i didn't find someone with the same problem.

Comment: You should provide some more details in order to get constructive feedback here. Do you have a particular problem when testing it? What's your development environment like?

Comment: I am not too familiar with testing (sadly), but isn't one of the advantages of MVC that you can test each component independent of the others? So you wouldn't test "a Kohana project", but your Models, Views (whatever that means) and Controllers

Comment: Basically, i have all the files and folders. I would like to test the views but i'm not too familiar with MVC. I have already prepared a default Kohana Project, a functional hello world to learn how it works.

Comment: I took a look at the Apache's error logand i found this error:Invalid command ‘RewriteEngine’, perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration. Now, i'm looking how to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

To anyone looking for an easy way to get stared with Kohana; I have released a vagrant development environment with an empty checkout of Kohana 3.3.1 and a bunch of external packages installed and ready to go.

[Intro to Vagrant with Kohana and Zen Kommerce](http://blog.jamieisaacs.com/2014/03/04/intro-to-vagrant-with-kohana-and-zen-kommerce/)